# Visual Studio .NET 2003 on Windows 7 hangs on search

Tags: visual-studio-2003

So I have Visual Studio 2003 running on Windows 7 - yeah I am aware it isn't officially supported - and no, unfortunately I can't change that situation :-(

For the most part it works OK but I have a specific problem, that I can't figure out. The application hangs if you do a project wide search (Ctrl - Shift - F) for a string.

I have a reasonably powerful machine and all the other heavy tasks like compiling and debugging all work fine. It also works if I restrict the search to the current document (Ctrl - F). I am running it as administrator and VS.NET 2003 SP1 has been applied.

The size of the project does not seem to be a problem since a colleague is also experiencing this issue for a single project solution containing 5 pages.

I am currently using Windows Search as a work-around and I was wondering if there is something I missed that I should try.

Comment: Never mind, I cross-posted this and got a better response in Serverfault and SuperUser.

Comment: I wrote a blog post detailing some of the stuff I needed to configure in order to get VS 2003 to work on Windows 7 - http://technikhil.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/visual-studio-2003-and-windows-7-can-get-along-really/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try disabling the Aero theme in compatibility. Yeah seriously...

Comment: Wow - That was the reason it hangs... I checked the compatibility setting to "Disable Desktop Compositing" and search started working.

Comment: If you don't see "Compatibility" tab (I don't have this tab for devenv.exe in Win8x64Pro, for example), run `regedit.exe`, then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and create `String` value with name `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` and value data `^ RUNASADMIN DISABLEDWM DISABLETHEMES`.

Comment: Worked for me on Vista, 7 and now 8 (using the monstrous registry trick). Many thanks.

Comment: izogfif's regstry hack worked for we with VS 2003 on Win7. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that works. In the German Version its called 'Visuelle Designs deaktivieren'.

Comment: @izogfif it seems to setting "Adjust for best performance" and adding the regkey you're talking about fix the problem for me in Win10

Comment: @Ivanzinho Try answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23662619/156973 with reg file. If that doesn't help, please provide more details about your issue: what do you do (step-by-step, if possible)? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?
P.S.: I wish there was a chat room on stackoverflow so we can avoid spamming the comments.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by right clicking the shortcut to launch VS.NET 2003 and selecting properties, choosing the “Compatibility” sub-tab and then checking “Disable Desktop Compositing” as well as “Disable Visual Themes”

Answer (score 5):

I use Windows 8.1, and the path
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]`
is invisible and could not be created manually inside regedit.exe.
So I wrote a registry file "abc.reg" with text:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe"="^ RUNASADMIN DISABLEDWM DISABLETHEMES"
```

Execute it by double click icon of "abc.reg" (may be Run As "Administrator").
It works.
(The post is for your convenience in this certain case)

Comment: Also confirm this works on Windows 10, v1803. You will need to maximise the window afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I am running **Windows 10 Enterprise 1909** and found global search also causes VS2003 to freeze and stop responding.

The advised registry edit did not work for me - VS2003 refuses to start up when run as admin:

`A referral was returned from the server.`

This is the same error I get if allowing the compatibility trouble-shooter to apply *Windows XP (Service Pack 3)*.

I **can** get global search working if I remove `RUNASADMIN` and `DISABLEDWM` from the registry value (I.E. leave only `DISABLETHEMES` in place).

Create a registry key as follows:

- Location: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`
- New: `String Value`
- Name: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`
- Value: `^ DISABLETHEMES`

You will end up with an even uglier UI (*quite an achievement in itself!*) but at least global search will now work.