# Legacy solution in Visual Studio .NET 2003 crashes when attaching to a process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I have a legacy solution in C#, .net 1.1 and Visual Studio .NET. My solution consists on many projects. Once I run in debug mode my initial project, then I attach to other processes. When I try to attach to a process, Visual Studio IDE crashes and I need to start IDE again. It's a pain!

Anyone has some idea on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Run as admin? Run with compatibility settings? What did you try already?

Comment: Seems like disabling some breakpoints is working a little bit better. As I have observed, visual studio does not like a lot of breakpoints...

Comment: @brijber Yes, I am running Visual Studio IDE as administrator.Regarding compatibility settings, I have no set nay for devenv.exe because when going to properties, "Compatibility" tab is not appearing for it.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422581/visual-studio-net-2003-on-windows-7-hangs-on-search

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a fix, but a way around it is to limit the number of processes you're attaching to.

Start with just connecting to one, then increase the number if stable.

To identify which project is running on each port you can run

IIS6

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs
```

IIS 7

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list wp
```